# setting all properties from properties file at once in java

Tags: java, hadoop, workflow, oozie

I am trying to set properties for an `oozieclient` in java which are read from a properties file. The properties file has 10 odd properties. Is there a way I can set these properties all at once and not have to read each key value pair from the file and then set them for the `oozieclient`?

```
OozieClient wc = new OozieClient(http://something:1100/oozie);

Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
conf.setProperty("jobTracker",....);
conf.setProperty("nameNode",......);
.
.
.
```

Instead of this, is there a way in which i can read these values from a properties file and set the values all at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read another property file and merge both:

```
OozieClient wc = new OozieClient("http://something:1100/oozie");

Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();
Properties p = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfile.properties");
p.load(fis);
conf.putAll(p);
fis.close(); // you still need to close the stream
```

With the file **myfile.properties** like:

```
jobTracker=foo
nameNode=bar
```

Take a look at the [Javadoc for Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following API: [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29). The load() operations on Properties can be given a reference to the .properties FileInputSteam or FileInputReader , it will read out all key-value pairs into your Properties-object.